# Is the Puppet Master's name Stromboli in Shrek the Third?

Tags: shrek, shrek-the-third

In *Shrek the Third*, we see the Puppet Master and we know it's him because of the following conversation with him and Prince Charming.

> **Prince Charming**: And you? Your star puppet [Pinocchio] abandons the show to go and find his father.
>
> **Puppet Master**: I hate that little wooden puppet.

It's unclear what his name is or what version of the character he's based off of, but in the video game, his level is called Stromboli's Workshop.

So *is* his name Stromboli after the Disney version?

Comment: calling him Stromboli, a name and arguably a characterization that Disney created, might not be a good idea for Dreamworks

Answer (score 7):

Chris Miller plays the part of the *"Puppet Master"* in the film. There's no specific evidence that his name is Stromboli other than in the licenced game.

[image: screenshot of end credits, Chris Miller's roles highlighted]